# parcel failed with css-loader.js: Invalid Version: undefined error

Tags: npm, css-loader, parcel

Have a small project. One html + css +js. I wanted to add parcel to it. Install it ( I don't have any more packages besides parcel).
in the package.json I did:

```js
 "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html"
  },
```

When I run npm start gives and error:

```js
C:\Users\ricar\OneDrive\Documentos\Web Developer\Projects\Blog Posts\DOM\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\builtins\css-loader.js: Invalid Version: undefined
```

There was any update that I am not aware and I do need something?
Thank you

Answer (score 10):

There's an issue with the latest version and you need to revert to version 1.12.3.

I used the following to fix it:

```
npm uninstall parcel-bundler
npm i --save-dev parcel-bundler@1.12.3
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that it works but it says that it has high vulnerabilities and then run npm audit fix. If I do it goes back to the new version of parcel. So I am not sure what is the best solution. How serious are the high vulnerabilities?

Comment: You may audit the vulnerabilities one by one ("manually") with `npm audit`.